# Borrowed value does not live long enough in a generic struct in Result - Map

Tags: rust, lifetime

```rust
impl<'a, T> ClientDBMain<T>
where
    T: FromRow<'a, PgRow>,
{
    async fn query_one(&self, pool: &PgPool, query_raw: &str) -> Result<T, MyError> {
        let res = sqlx::query(query_raw)
            .fetch_one(pool)
            .await
            .map(|r: PgRow| {
                // error here
                T::from_row(&r).unwrap()
            })
            .map_err(|err| {
                // to save for brevity
            })?;
        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

`r` in `map()` does not live long enough.

What is the life span of `r`?

How to solve this problem? By enforcing longer life time, at least as `a`? Is there any way to manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost definitely want to use a higher-ranked trait bound:

```
impl<T> ClientDBMain<T>
where
    T: for<'a> FromRow<'a, PgRow>,
    // ^^^^^^^
{
    async fn query_one(&self, pool: &PgPool, query_raw: &str) -> Result<T, MyError> {
        ...
```

Your original code was communicating that `T` could only be made from a `PgRow` if the row had a specific lifetime. There is no way that an external lifetime would be appropriate for `r` which only lives within that closure. Instead, the `for<'a>` introduces a generic lifetime, essentially saying that `T` implements `FromRow` for any lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

`r` appears to have a `'static` lifetime, however since it does not get moved it will be dropped upon falling out of scope at the end of the `map`. The issue is that `FromRow` may produce a value referencing `r` meaning it can not outlive `r`. Since it appear that the way it does this is probably via `'a`, you can probably fix this by requiring `T: FromRow<'static, PgRow>`. If the resulting type has a `'static` lifetime then it would not be reliant of the lifetime of `r`.

```rust
impl<T> ClientDBMain<T>
where
    T: FromRow<'static, PgRow>,
{
    async fn query_one(&self, pool: &PgPool, query_raw: &str) -> Result<T, MyError> {
        let res = sqlx::query(query_raw)
            .fetch_one(pool)
            .await
            .map(|r: PgRow| {
                // error here
                T::from_row(&r).unwrap()
            })
            .map_err(|err| {
                // to save for brevity
            })?;
        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a "random" check: will the lifetime `'static` introduce unnecessary consumptions?

Comment: Even with `'static` lifetime, `r` still cannot live long enough.

Comment: @Leon I just checked the docs. Looks like `'a` didn't matter, but we can still constrain the lifetime of `T`. So just use `T: 'static + FromRow<'a, PgRow>`. It won't introduce any complications. At first when I was learning I thought that by requiring something  be `'static` it might not get dropped, but what it really means is that a lifetime is completely unconstrained so if given the opportunity it would be able to live for the entire length of the program.